# Create new elements using `document.createElement`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datepicker, frontend

I need to insert a ["date-picker"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) using `document.createElement`. Maybe because of its nature of not being built-in block of HTML, such a manner doesn't show the picker element as others. Is there any alternative?

Snippet:

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
        var a = document.getElementById("addexp");
    
        var compName = document.createElement("input");
        var picker = document.createElement("DatePicker");
        var description = document.createElement("textarea");
        var submit = document.createElement("button");
        
        compName.setAttribute("class","input-box__reference");
        compName.setAttribute("placeholder","Company Name")
        compName.setAttribute("name","compName");

        picker.setAttribute("selected", startDate);
        picker.setAttribute("onChange", (date) => setStartDate(date));
    
        description.setAttribute("class","input-box__bio");
        description.setAttribute("placeholder","Description")
        description.setAttribute("name","description");

        submit.setAttribute("class","sign-btn");
        submit.setAttribute("type","submit");
        submit.innerHTML = 'Submit';
    
        a.appendChild(compName);
        a.appendChild(description);
        a.appendChild(submit);
        a.appendChild(cancel);
```

Comment: That's a React package, It only works with React.js, not plain HTML/JS.

Comment: In plain JS you'd do `let inp = document.createElement('input'); inp.type = "date";document.body.appendChild(inp);` or similar for the browser's default date selector.

Comment: I'm confused, what does it have to be `input`?

Comment: [MDN: *input type=date*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) You asked "*Is there any alternative?*" I'm not expecting you to prefer the default date picker (hence comment not answer) but it is an alternative. :-)

Comment: That's brilliant!